# Open magnetic resonance imaging datasets on psychosis?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, neuroimaging, data

Are there any open magnetic resonance imaging datasets of normal and healthy adults (as controls) and psychotic subjects?

Such as ADNI for Alzheimer's or OASIS for aging.

Comment: This link shows preliminary findings of magnetite in human brains with higher level found in Alzheimer's patients. I am a shark researcher and plan to do testing with em fields here in Hawaii with our sharks. I hope this helps you.                             http://www.pnas.org/content/89/16/7683.full.pdf.

Comment: @Brandon I think you have misunderstood what magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) is about.

Answer (score 1):

The Australian Schizophrenia Research Bank (http://www.schizophreniaresearch.org.au/bank/research-information/information-on-datasample-availability-for-researchers/) has an 'open' database of clinical MRI (T1s and DTI) as well as healthy controls. Access isn't free though - they charge an administration fee to cover costs. It is an ongoing effort and I think there is about 500 MRIs from patients in there now, but I'm not sure what the latest numbers are exactly.